# How to enable HttpInterceptor

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular-http-interceptors

I have created httpInterceptor in backend SpringBoot and keeping my API key in application.properties.

I have to enable HttpInterceptor somewhere in Angular service in Http header but I dont know how I can do it

Comment: can you be more specific with your question?

Answer (score 0):

you mean how to register you interceptor? you can add it as provider in your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [  
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BackendRequestInterceptor, multi: true},
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Register the interceptor like Andreas posted in his answer and then implement it. Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthDirectusService } from './auth-directus.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthDirectusService) {}

    intercept(req, next) {
        if(this.authService.getToken() != null)
        {
            let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                      Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
                }
            })
            return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
        }else{
            let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
            }
        })
        return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you will be keeping api-key? for example- api-key = "3hjdhj35xcbhb"

Comment: There is no way to completely hide the API key in your client-side code. If you are making the request straight from your client-side code, no matter what you do, anyone can go into the browsers dev-tools and get your API key. You can encrypt the key, but even that is not a fool proof solution.
I have solved the issue by creating my own server side API, that handles that stuff.  I authenticate at my API with cookie based JWT.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Can you give some example how you have created server side API? is it node or Java?

Comment: I created server side API in NodeJS using 'express' for REST and 'express-jwt' for JSON Web Token functionality.